# Apply different symbology layers to different dataframes with arcpy mapping?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, symbology, data-frame

I have one shapefile, which I want to create a map of with 3 different data frames (showing three different attributes of the shapefile) on one map. I have 3 separate symbology layers files saved to be applied to each dataframe. I have got as far as loading in the shapefile to each data frame, and can apply the same symbology layer to each, but can't get different symbology layers to go to different dataframes. I want this to be automated as eventually I want to loop this over a large number of shapefiles to make multiple maps, but I just can't work out this beginning step.

So far I have:

```
import arcpy,

shape = arcpy.mapping.Layer("myshapefile.shp")
symbologyLayer =("mysymbology.lyr") 


for df in arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd):
 arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, shape, "AUTO_ARRANGE")
 arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management (shape, symbologyLayer)
```

Answer (score 1):

1. add a suffix to each symbology layer that corresponds to the order of the dataframes (first dataframe would be mysymbology_0.lyr, second would be mysymbology_1.lyr)
2. put into a list like so:  `[mysymbology_0.lyr, mysymbology_2.lyr, mysymbology_3.lyr]`
3. Modify your script as follows:

   `symbologyLayerList = [mysymbology_0.lyr, mysymbology_2.lyr, mysymbology_3.lyr]
    i = 0
    for df in arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd):
        arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, shape, "AUTO_ARRANGE")
        arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management (shape, symbologyLayerList[i])
        i+=1`

This may not be the best solution for your question, but it will accomplish what you are asking.  You might want to ask another question(s) about how to automate the symbology layers /naming symbology layers / building a list of named symbology layers.